# Why does Webdriver no longer find elements after using Robot to download in IE

Tags: java, selenium, awtrobot

I am automating a file download from a site using Java Robot in IE.

At the conclusion of the download, the driver can no longer finds elements, including ones I've just used. I've checked that the driver still has the same window handler.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://somepage");

Robot robot = new Robot();        
WebElement exportButton = driver.findElement("//*[contains(@href,'stuff')]");

exportButton.sendKeys("");

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

// Wait for Save As dialog            
Thread.sleep(2000);

// Tab over to Save button
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
Thread.sleep(2000);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); 
Thread.sleep(2000);

// Press Enter on Save button
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

// This will throw a Webdriver Exception that it could not be found.
driver.findElement("//*[contains(@href,'stuff')]);
```

This last findElement fails, as does any other previously working xpaths.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] if you expect an answer.

Comment: sorry about that, I added the driver inits and page get.

Answer (score 0):

Your current issue is that browser has lost focus from the web page to some browser dialog after all those Robot manipulations.

Generally speaking, it's not the best solution to download files with WebDriver. Why do you need to download file? Are you going to do smth with it? Why do you use IE for that, not Chrome of Firefox?

Long answer about this is perferctly explained here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver.

In short, you better use some 3rd party library / http client to download files.

Comment: The file is being downloaded as part of our e2e test suite.  We need to download and then validate the file contents as part of our test.  It's a long story as to why we can't just get the link and download directly, it won't work with the security of the system under test. We test Chrome and Firefox as well and they work wonderfully.  Sadly about 10% of our customer base is still using IE, so we are required to test it as well.

Comment: So I definitely understand this isn't a desirable test, but its one we've been tasked to automate specifically for IE.